# Issue remotely debugging java cloud application with vscode

Tags: java, azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions, vscode-debugger

I figured i'll post the question on stackoverflow as well.  https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/450

I'm having issue remotely debugging an azure function that is deployed to azure.  I'm following the following instruction https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/master/docs/java/java-azurefunctions.md.

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloud-debug-tools which successfully connects, but I get an exception when i try to remotely connect to the debug port via vscode.

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this question is already getting traction on GitHub: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2986. I suggest following up there since the product team is already investigating.